# Error with installing cardano-wallet on Ubuntu

Tags: wallet, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to install cardano-wallet with [this guide](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet).
I tried a few times and every time I got this error:

```
ouroboros-consensus-byron        > Registering library for ouroboros-consensus-byron-0.1.0.0..
Progress 461/475

--  While building package plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0 configure --with-ghc=/root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/bin/ghc-8.10.7 --with-ghc-pkg=/root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/bin/ghc-pkg-8.10.7 --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/pkgdb --libdir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/lib --bindir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/bin --datadir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/share --libexecdir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/libexec --sysconfdir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/etc --docdir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/doc/plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 --htmldir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/doc/plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 --haddockdir=/root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/7d9a5133e73e69eafb80db950076b4ec70696c4137ef4c6e05d111373f4a3891/8.10.7/doc/plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 --dependency=aeson=aeson-1.5.6.0-63wWHA3GHE0Isomy9OHMEw --dependency=base=base-4.14.3.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.12.0 --dependency=containers=containers-0.6.4.1-D3v2li2ijuF82lK0hW01Nr --dependency=deepseq=deepseq-1.4.4.0 --dependency=filepath=filepath-1.4.2.1 --dependency=flat=flat-0.4.5-4g0HMvnhh6wwWCZXBuoYZ --dependency=ghc-prim=ghc-prim-0.6.1 --dependency=hashable=hashable-1.3.0.0-IsmIrOikObW5VAtLT8nz0o --dependency=lens=lens-4.19.2-jJTa5AeuDm5NTBTeWMq3U --dependency=memory=memory-0.15.0-12G9mJuoNajBX4ohDjVYqb --dependency=mtl=mtl-2.2.2 --dependency=plutus-core=plutus-core-0.1.0.0-HQxTtycJGU52DKsUbNhuCn --dependency=prettyprinter=prettyprinter-1.7.1-89YQ13YwDjX8F1jciVrjTL --dependency=serialise=serialise-0.2.4.0-DiNk09iYdO3InRp0kGWlZg --dependency=tagged=tagged-0.8.6.1-HAjNeIkiYpIE28bnkAmrHX --dependency=tasty=tasty-1.4.2.1-B5isyoZJH1FIanpsobqwTE --dependency=template-haskell=template-haskell-2.16.0.0 --dependency=text=text-1.2.4.0-8O4eYxmKONuI5wWkW4xxj2 --dependency=th-abstraction=th-abstraction-0.4.3.0-EPNdba1m5DICfgheXpc0BJ --dependency=th-compat=th-compat-0.1.3-5V8hDdHCkmaDnfC7yeUenV --exact-configuration --ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are there any more useful messages above what you have posted?

Comment: You might be on an old version of Cabal, I noticed 'Cabal-3.2.1.0' in your error message. `cardano-node` wants version 3.6.2.0, wallet might be similar.
Did you also build `cardano-node` as per the wallet guide suggestion? If so that will confirm that cabal etc is ok.
`cardano-node` setup link (if needed): https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/

Comment: @MC_Brisbane Thank you for replying. Sure I built cardano-node and have needed versions. 

cardano-node 1.34.1 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10,
git rev 73f9a746362695dc2cb63ba757fbcabb81733d23,
cabal-install version 3.6.2.0,
compiled using version 3.6.2.0 of the Cabal library

Comment: Scroll up a few lines from the error message to get more details relating to 'plutus-tx'. Also, are you running as the same user that built the cardano-node? Could be some shared objects. PlanB - if you're in a hurry you could grab the binary instead of building it.

Comment: Working only under root, [here](https://imgur.com/a/oQvctpe) is the full error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error on my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (with 8GB RAM, no other Cardano code was on this machine).

Initially it failed at a different spot 'Progress 445/475' and re-running the build ended up like your situation eg:

```
plutus-tx                      > Configuring plutus-tx-0.1.0.0...
plutus-tx                      > Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7: Encountered missing or private     [<--- NOTE]
plutus-tx                      > dependencies:
plutus-tx                      > plutus-core:{plutus-core, plutus-core-testlib} ==0.1.0.0
plutus-tx                      > 
Progress 7/21           

--  While building package plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
    ...
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Note the missing dependencies lines.

I decided to use the *previous wallet version* (not the latest), in case it was more stable ie v2022-01-18.

The below is what worked for me to get it to build ok:

1. Stop some other processes to free up RAM if you only have 8GB like me.
2. I installed `libsodium`, you probably won't need this step if you have built `cardano-node` successfully
3. Start the whole download/build process over again in a new directory but this time use the previous stable code release eg `git checkout v2022-01-18`
4. Run the build, it should complete eg `stack build --test --no-run-tests`

I don't have `cardano-node` on this machine so can not run the wallet as intended but `cardano-wallet version` looks ok:

> cardano-wallet version
> v2022-01-18 (git revision: a5085acbd2670c24251cf8d76a4e83c77a2679ba)

Comment: `git checkout v2022-01-18` is really working for me. Great thanx!

Comment: Great, am pleased to hear it. I'm not sure of the actual root cause, but we might find that as other code in the repo gets updated over then next few days/weeks that it all comes right and plays together nicely again.